# Erro ao tentar salvar no BD

Tags: javascript, laravel, react

Estou usando o react e quando tento salvar no banco de dados me retorna esse erro:

> `Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined`

Meu codigo é esse:

```
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api/employee";

import axios from 'axios';

const employee = {};

employee.list = async () => {
    const urlList = baseUrl + "/role";
    const res = await axios.get(urlList)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        })
    return res;
}
employee.save = async (data) => {
    const urlSave = baseUrl + "/create";
    const res = await axios.post(urlSave.data)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        })
    return res;
}

export default employee;
```

uma ultima informação meu vs code acusa que o `data` do employee.save não está sendo usado em lugar nenhum já tentei usar o `this` e mudar o caminho no `.env` e nada funciona alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: está uma mistura com os seus `promise` ou usa `async` e `await` ou o método `then`, ou seja, o código está escrito totalmente errado e por isso de erros estranhos.

Comment: Quando você envia o post, você tem que enviar os dados. Por exemplo: Vocês está fazendo assim `await axios.post(urlSave.data)`, acho que você quis fazer assim: `await axios.post(urlSave, data)`. E outra, se você for usar o `await` não  então não se usa o `then` nem `catch`

Comment: verdade outro problema que passou desapercebido @adventistaam, além dos `promise`, não foi passado o valor no `post`!

Comment: E até onde eu sei, primeiro se configura o `axios`. `const http = axios.create( ({baseURL: urlbase })`. E daí se usa os verbos: `http.get(), http.post(), etc`

Comment: Não @adventistaam, não é regra para funcionar, não é obrigatório!

Comment: Ah, ta! Blz.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você você está usando um ponto `(.)` no lugar da vírgula `(,)` para enviar os dados

Outra coisa interessante é que você está usando `async` e `then` `catch` na sua função

```
employee.save = async (data) => {
    const urlSave = baseUrl + "/create";
    const res = await axios.post(urlSave.data)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        })
    return res;
}
```

No trecho `axios.post(urlSave.data)`, tente substituir por `axios.post(urlSave, data)`

E na parte dos retornos por você pode tanto assim:

```
 const res = await axios.post(urlSave.data)
 return res;
```

Ficando no final sua função assim:

```
employee.save = async (data) => {
    const urlSave = baseUrl + "/create";
    const res = await axios.post(urlSave, data)
    return res;
}
```

Ou assim:

```
const res = axios.post(urlSave.data)
                 .then(response => {
                      response.data 
                  }).catch(error => {
                       console.log(error)
                  })
```

Aí nesse último para você obter os valorse você terá que usar uma promise

Ficando assim:

```
employee.save = (data) => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         const urlSave = baseUrl + "/create";
         axios.post(urlSave, data)
              .then(response => {
                 resolve( response.data );
               })
               .catch(error => {
                   reject(error)
               })
          })
```

Aí para obter o valor nessa função teria que ser usando usando async ou then

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, tente fazer dessa forma utilizando apenas o async/await. O que você fez foi utilizar as pormisses junto com async/await, o que é errado. Além de não ter iniciado a instancia do axios.

```
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api/employee";
    
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseUrl: baseUrl
});
    
const employee = {};
    
employee.list = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.get('/role')

    return data;
  } catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
};

employee.save = async (data) => {
  try {
    const { data: respData } = await api.post('/create', data)

    return respData;
  } catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
}

export default employee;
```

Comment: uma ressalva não precisa e não é regra que precise utilizar `create` no `axios`, você pode ou não utilizar, facilita sim se for utilizado em vários lugares com a mesmo endereço, mas não é obrigatório.

Comment: Sim, concordo com você @novic, não é obrigatório, mais facilita o entendimento e seria ate melhor se estive em um arquivo separado.